# Unable to instantiate default tuplizer - Could not locate field name [hash] on class

Tags: java, hibernate, pojo

I have Maven project with Hibernate and simple POJO class. I have found similar problems in the forums, but always write about javaassist and does not match the method names getter/setter or not available.
**If add hash filed to class, next error - not locate field name [value].**

Hibernate configuration - http://codeshare.io/G8cRT

POJO - http://codeshare.io/Qv968

When I try execute simple query - list table contents, get stacktrace error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:98)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PropertyFactory.buildStandardProperty(PropertyFactory.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentMetamodel.<init>(ComponentMetamodel.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component.getType(Component.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:531)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:443)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.buildSessionFactory(MetadataImpl.java:170)
    at com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:19)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.ComponentTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(ComponentTuplizerFactory.java:95)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not locate field name [hash] on class [com.zvpblog.OraHib.model.Crs]
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.findField(ReflectHelper.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessFieldImpl.<init>(PropertyAccessFieldImpl.java:34)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.internal.PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.buildPropertyAccess(PropertyAccessStrategyFieldImpl.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getGetter(Property.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.buildGetter(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.AbstractComponentTuplizer.<init>(AbstractComponentTuplizer.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.component.PojoComponentTuplizer.<init>(PojoComponentTuplizer.java:42)
```

Query part:

```
public class CrsDAOImpl implements CrsDAO {

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Crs> listCrs() {
    Session session = null;
    ArrayList<Crs> list = null;
    try {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        list = (ArrayList<Crs>) session.createQuery("from Crs").list();
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error in CrsDAOImpl -> listCrs");
    } finally {
        if (session != null)
        session.close();
    }
    return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the query you are trying to use, select / insert / .... you pojo does not have any attrubite called hash, but I think your script has

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala add query part code to question

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, within few steps:

1. Change Embeddable class for primary key to `static`.

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public static class CrsPk implements Serializable {...}
   ```
2. Add @Column annotation to primary key class fields.

   ```
   @Embeddable
   public static class CrsPk implements Serializable {        
       @Column(name = "CCRSISO", columnDefinition = "CHAR")
       private String cCrsIso;
       @Column(name = "DCRSDATE", columnDefinition = "DATE")
       private Date dCrsDate;
       ...
   }
   ```

Comment: What if I'm using IdClass? Same problem here

Comment: I can't put static on class, it says it is not possible